# What is bezier_conf.path1 in cocos2d(python)

Tags: python, cocos2d-python

I'm learning cocos2d(python).When i watch cocos2d Documentation on webpage([cocos2d documentation](http://python.cocos2d.org/doc/api/cocos.actions.interval_actions.html#cocos.actions.interval_actions.Bezier)).There are some code as follows:

```
action = Bezier(bezier_conf.path1, 5)   # Moves the sprite using the
sprite.do(action)                       # bezier path 'bezier_conf.path1'
                                      # in 5 seconds
```

and no more code.I don't understande what is 'bezier_conf.path1' and what value is i used to defined it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install package

```
pip install --upgrade bezier
```

Small example

```
import numpy as np
import bezier

n1 = np.array([[0.0, 1.0],[1.5, 1.0],[1.0, 0.0],])
n2 = np.array([[0.0, 0.0],[1.0, 1.0],[1.0, 2.5],])
curve1 = bezier.Curve(n1, degree=2)
curve2 = bezier.Curve.from_nodes(n2)
intersections = curve1.intersect(curve2)

print (intersections)
```

The intersection between two curves is calculated in this example.You need to import bezier for your code.

Comment: I get 'ValueError: path '/home/ubuntu/bezier/src/bezier/speedup.f90' cannot be absolute' when I execut 'pip install --upgrade bezier'.I use windows 10

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 16.04,this is for Linux installation.

Comment: I get bezier source on gitHub and i download it.so I can install it on windows10.Thank you!

Comment: I figure out.This 'bezier_conf.path1' actually is the 'cocos.path.Bezier'.Because I use cocos2d-x(python),It already include bezier.now I finally find how to use it.